# Curl websockets

Tags: bash, curl, websocket

I'm working on one bash script. I need to get data from websocket on my esp32. I need to get value from the sensor. Issue is that sometimes I can't get connection right when i send request.

```
flow_value_raw=$(timeout 1s \
        curl \
        --no-buffer \
        --header "Connection: Upgrade" \
        --header "Upgrade: websocket" \
        --header "Host: $ip$port/$flow" \
        --header "Origin: http://$ip$port/$flow" \
        --header "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" \
        --header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" \
        http://$ip:$port/$flow 2>/dev/null) 
        flow_value_raw=${flow_value_raw:2}
```

In this way I trigger curl every sec, but lot of time I get nothing from curl. Is there any way I can tell curl to just get one value from respond? If i use just curl without timeout I get multiple response.

Answer (score 0):

i am not entirely sure what you mean or seek.

so i am trying to respond to

> any whay i can tell curl to just get one value from respond

a `while`-loop where the condition is `true` will continue indefinitely. an infinite loop

the output from `curl` is saved in `flow_value_raw`

`if [ -n "${flow_value_raw} ]` checks if the string variable **non-empty**
- if non-empty, i.e. values were outputted by curl, `break` out of infinite loop
- else `sleep` for `1` second and repeat

```sh
while true; do
    local flow_value_raw=$(timeout 1 curl ...args)
    if [ -n "${flow_value_raw}" ]; then
      break
    else
      sleep 1
    fi
done
```

PS from [`man timeout`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html#:%7E:text=Start%20COMMAND%2C%20and%20kill%20it%20if%20still%20running%20after%20DURATION.)

> Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.